# How to update some Key information from another Project

Tags: ms-project-2016

I have created a Project in MS Project 2016. Of this data there are probably about 50 tasks which are of high importance.

What I would like to do is create a project with the most important 50 tasks, so that, if any of the information about these 50 tasks is updated in the small project, the data in the large project is also updated and vice versa. The other data in the large project is not so important.

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this? I have not yet come across anything that appears to be useful at the moment and I would like a response by Monday. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: A full answer to this will take too long.  I suggest you have a look at this public domain video by John Purvis from last year's MSP Virtual Conference - called Project Planning Using a Key Milestone Project.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D47JD9UWThk&list=PLR600A4mBfHjnaHwG_h0vLiWhrDdDmsDR&index=28

Comment: Tom, Thanks for pointing me in the direction of youtube. It has been of great help.